# How to set Gender User Property manually in Firebase Analytics?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

Firebase collects some user properties automatically but the question is, how does Firebase know what the user's gender is?

I tried to set them programmatically but it didn't help because there's no data about genders on the Firebase Console. In other word, setting predefined user properties programmatically could not be collected by Firebase.

```
mFirebaseAnalytics.setUserId(Long.toString(user.id));
mFirebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty("Gender", user.sex);
mFirebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty("Age", Integer.toString(age.getYears()));
```

**Note:** I'm using free plan and I waited for +24 hours to see the result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Firebase collects some user properties automatically but the question is, how does Firebase know what the user's gender is?

From this [help article](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317486):

> Demographics and interests data comes from anonymous identifiers for mobile apps (i.e., Advertising ID for Android and IDFA for iOS).

You cannot set or override the built-in user properties yourself, however if you believe you have better data for each user you can create a custom user property and set that yourself to be used separately to the built-in value.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I already knew that Firebase collects some properties automatically but I don't know how it does that while I save my users' gender in my own database.

Comment: No worries. Did my answer cover it or was something still not clear?

Comment: Everything is clear and thanks for your time. I only have another simple question. Should I set `setUserId()`?

Comment: If it's easy to set then it can't hurt, but AFAIK it's only useful when accessing data outside of the console right now (such as exporting to BigQuery). It won't affect any of your Firebase console reports in terms of identifying users.

Answer (score 5):

User properties created in code need to be registered in the Firebase console to view them there. The default user properties (Age, Gender etc) however cannot be registered in the console, since they already exist.

Comment: So just use a different name, not a big deal.
E.g. app_age, app_gender